# Java JSCH - send EOF in exec or shell channel

Tags: java, jsch

I'm trying to send the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (^C) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (^D) behavior to the SSH server using Java's JSCH.

I currently have no idea on how I would send an EOF message through the exec or ssh channel.

Can anyone help me with this?

Edit:

Below the code I'm trying to execute:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class Test {

    private static final JSch JSCH_INSTANCE = new JSch();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Session session = JSCH_INSTANCE.getSession("username", "domain");
        session.setPassword("password");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        InputStream err = channel.getErrStream();
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.setCommand("sudo service rscedit start");
        channel.connect();
        while (channel.getExitStatus() == -1) {
            Thread.sleep(10);//command stays stuck here because EOF isn't being sent?
        }
        InputStream result = err.available() > 0 ? err : in;
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while(result.available() > 0) {
            responseBuilder.append((char) result.read());
        }
        System.out.println(responseBuilder);
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }

}
```

The service is executing the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
(java -jar -Xmx20480m /home/path/Somejar.jar)
read –n1
```

Can I add EOF at the end of the command?

Comment: In discussing your issue, it'd be helpful for you to add the code that you have for sending data through jsch to the remote system. Highlight the point in the code where you'd like to send these characters.

Comment: What for? Handling `Ctrl+C/D` is something done in an interactive shell sessions. You generally should use different techniques when automating command execution. So please explain us, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I've updated the question with code.

Comment: So when you run `sudo service rscedit start` in shell, it does not return to the prompt on its own? Do you really need to press `Ctrl+C/D`?

Comment: Yes. Here's a gif: https://i.imgur.com/3c09zIx.gif

I must replicate the CTRL + C behavior else I can't get a response in my exec channel when executing the command.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the "rscedit" service start script to me. --- As such there's no *correct* solution -- all you are looking for, is the best workaround. ---- At the point your press `Ctrl+C`, is the service already running? - Or does something wait for `Ctrl+C` to actually start the service? --- If you kill PuTTY process at that moment, would the service work correctly?

Comment: The 'rscedit' service is executing the bash script that's in the question. The service starts on the background. After CTRL + C too. The service works correctly and I can kill the service after I've started it. I can make another gif if you want.
I can kill the process too.

Comment: If any of the answers is right, consider upvoting / marking as correct to help others with similar problem.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow. Have been busy with other things lately. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in the "rscedit" service start script to me.

As such there's no *correct* solution -- all you are looking for, is the best workaround.

From your comments, it does not look like you actually need to send <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. The service is already up and running when the startup script *hangs.

So you can just close the channel instead, maybe after a short time interval. That's effectively the same as what <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> does in an interactive terminal.